# Running standalone app using QWebEngineView created with PyInstaller on MacOS gives Couldn't mmap icu data file

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qwebengineview

I want to create a standalone application, which used `PyQt5 QWebEngineView`. Creating the application with `PyInstaller` gives the following error when the application is executed:

`Couldn't mmap icu data file`

The error only arises on MacOS and only if `--onefile` mode is used. On Windows I don't have that problem.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69433786/couldnt-mmap-icu-data-file-in-pyqt5) is a solution given in Chinese, which I don't understand.

I create a basic program to show the error:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
import sys

class App(QMainWindow):
    abort = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        webView = QWebEngineView()
        webView.load(QUrl("https://www.google.de/"))

        self.setCentralWidget(webView)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = App()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The spec-file looks like this:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['test.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='tesst',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

I use:

- PyInstaller: 5.0.1
- Python: 3.9.9
- Platform: macOS-10.16-x86_64-i386-64bit

I gladly provide further info, if needed

Comment: Did you figure out how to do it in onefile mode? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I still have not found a solution

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on Windows with Qt 5.15.2x32 MSVC2019

Solution: copy all files from `C:\Qt\Qt5.15.2\5.15.2\msvc2019\resources` to folder with your exe-file (The path to the folder "resources" depends on the version of the Qt. You can find the path by filename from the list below).

List of files:

- icudtl.dat
- qtwebengine_devtools_resources.pak
- qtwebengine_resources.pak
- qtwebengine_resources_100p.pak
- qtwebengine_resources_200p.pak

If you use `windeployqt.exe`, this tool is copying folder `resources` near to your exe, it is wrong, you should to move all files from `resources` to one level up (to folder with your exe-file)

Comment: Copying the resource folder the folder, where the exe is, works. Unfortunately, including it in the spec-file as `a.datas += Tree('path/to/Resources', prefix='Resources')` does not.